# Column compression

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have two columns wits content. The first column should do automatic compression and second column should do fixed. If first column not have enough space than it should do compression. The content of the first column should do to go to fade. Sizes columns not known in advance. How do it make?

```html
<div class="container" style="display: flex;">
  <div class="left" style="display: flex;">
    <a>
      First
    </a>
    <a>
      Second
    </a>
    <a>
      Third
    </a>
    <a>
      44444
    </a>
    <a>
      5555
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="right" style="display: flex;">
    <div>1234213321312</div>
    <div>More content</div>
    <div>Button button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Size of `first` should also take all available space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Add flex-grow: 1; if you need the block to take all remaining space; */
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0; /* don't shrink */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <a>
      First
    </a>
    <a>
      Second
    </a>
    <a>
      Third
    </a>
    <a>
      44444
    </a>
    <a>
      5555
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div>1234213321312</div>
    <div>More content</div>
    <div>Button button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```